# header ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response

Tags: laravel, api, cors, nuxt.js

my problem is that I can't send data via post to my api -> cors.

I am struggling with this issue for days now.. My attempt to find a solution failed so far - threads with the same issue had solutions I have already tried.

Here is the error from the console:

header ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response

here is my config/cors.php:

```
'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false
```

Kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,                  <----- Cors Middleware
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Sometimes it was suggested to move \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class to a different position within the array -> no result

Here is my axios request from the nuxt component:

```
async register() {
      let config = {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
      await this.$axios
        .$post(
          '/api/v1/register',
          {
            ...this.form,
            password_confirmation: this.form.password,
          },
          config
        )
        .then(() => {}
}
```

I quite the beginner with API's and don't truly understand with point is causing the CORS error.
If it is a problem with Laravel or Nuxt.

I already tried to add the required headers (as suggested in various posts) to the routes/api.php and index.php in the public folder and external in the .htaccess without success. Of course not at the same time...

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score -1):

If you pass a JSON object as the second argument to the axios.post method, axios will automatically serialise it to JSON for you. It will also set the Content-Type header.

Try removing your explicit header declaration.

```
async register() {
  await this.$axios
    .$post(
      '/api/v1/register',
      {
        ...this.form,
        password_confirmation: this.form.password,
      })
      .then(() => {})
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reading my question. I removed the header argument but the response didn't change - still got the CORS error

Comment: Is it the exact same error, referring to the content type header?

Comment: I’ve been looking in to this. What version of laravel are you using?